# Unable to login to admin dashboard in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

When I log in to my site as an admin or user, I am getting the below errors;

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/u659267041/domains/zoomqatar.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/menu.php on line 167

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/u659267041/domains/zoomqatar.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1560
```

Can anyone help solve this?

Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

Comment: Disable all of your plugins. Is it still happening?

Comment: in php.ini use `display_errors=Off`

Comment: #JasonB yes, even if i disable all plugins its happening

Comment: #Tamil Selvan to which file i may add this tag?

Comment: #Harsh i dont see any relevance in that thread, did you miss anything?